# What exactly is `&:capitalize` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I just read this answer [Converting upper-case string into title-case using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791639/regular-expression-in-ruby-to-convert-uppercase-title-into-lowercase/1792102#1792102).

There is the following line of code

```
"abc".split(/(\W)/).map(&:capitalize).join
```

What exactly is `&:capitalize`? Before I had put this into irb myself, I would have told you, it's not valid ruby syntax. It must be some kind of `Proc` object, because `Array#map` normaly takes a block. But it isn't. If I put it into irb alone, I get `syntax error, unexpected tAMPER`.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work in irb for you is probably because, like sepp2k says, it was only baked into the standard library in Ruby 1.8.7, and I'm guessing you're running an earlier version. You see it pretty frequently, though, because ActiveSupport also throws it in, and ActiveSupport comes with Rails. If you try it in Rails' script/console you'll probably discover it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foo(&a_proc_object)` turns `a_proc_object` into a block and calls foo with that block.

`foo(&not_a_proc_object)` calls `to_proc` on `not_a_proc_object` and then turns the proc object returned by `to_proc` into a block and calls foo with that block.

In ruby 1.8.7+ and active support `Symbol#to_proc` is defined to return a proc which calls the method named by the symbol on the argument to the proc.

Answer (score 5):

It's `Symbol#to_proc`: see http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html

`map(&:capitalize)` is exactly the same as `map { |x| x.capitalize }`.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, since there is a performance impact to the former.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand is syntactic sugar that does a whole bunch of code generation with the `to_proc` message. See http://blog.codahale.com/2006/08/01/stupid-ruby-tricks-stringto_proc/