# Ruby on Rails: Converting "SomeWordHere" to "some word here"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know you can do something like:

```
"SomeWordHere".underscore.gsub("_", " ")
```

to get "some word here".

I thought that might be a little too much for something so simple. Is there a more efficient way (maybe a built-in method?) to convert "SomeWordHere" to "some word here"?

Comment: By "a more efficient way" are you referring to runtime performance or something else?

Comment: Could your input contain anything other than CamelCaseWords such as punctuation, spaces, underscores, digits, words in all capitals, etc...?

Comment: ... or accented characters ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[image]

The methods **underscore** and **humanize** are designed for conversions between tables, class/package names, etc. You are better off using your own code to do the replacement to avoid surprises. See comments.

```
"SomeWordHere".underscore => "some_word_here"

"SomeWordHere".underscore.humanize => "Some word here"

"SomeWordHere".underscore.humanize.downcase => "some word here"
```

Comment: Look at the implementation of underscore and humanize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509915/converting-camel-case-to-underscore-case-in-ruby http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6350 - there's a lot of string operations in there and this is arguably more complex than the OP's original suggestion.

Comment: Sorry better link - humanize for strings: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/Inflector.html#M001633

Comment: `underscore` and `humanize` are not only over-blown but also incorrect for OP's purposes. For example,  `"UserId".underscore.humanize` gives `"User"`. `underscore`has its own replacements. For example, `"ABC::UserId".underscore` gives `"abc/user_id"`. You're right, a custom implementation is the way to go.

Comment: && OP: Those functions are open source so if a custom implementation is needed, it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is a simpler solution:

`"SomeWordHere".titleize.downcase`

Comment: Interesting: `titleize` uses the same logic as `humanize`. 
So the same caveats apply (`"SomeWordHereId".titleize` will strip the 'id')

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression:

```
puts "SomeWordHere".gsub(/[a-zA-Z](?=[A-Z])/, '\0 ').downcase
```

Output:

```
some word here
```

One reason you might prefer this is if your input could contain dashes or underscores and you don't want to replace those with spaces:

```
puts "Foo-BarBaz".underscore.gsub('_', ' ')
puts "Foo-BarBaz".gsub(/[a-zA-Z](?=[A-Z])/, '\0 ').downcase
```

Output:

```
foo bar baz
foo-bar baz
```

Comment: Though then the output is still in titlecase.

Comment: You can use `String#downcase` to make it all lowercase.

Comment: Though the question is whether it's still more efficient ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nope there is no built-in method that I know of. Any more efficient then a one-liner? Don't thinks so. Maybe `humanize` instead of the `gsub`, but you don't get exactly the same output.

Comment: Just because it's a "one liner" doesn't mean it's efficient (assuming he means runtime performance). Look at the source code for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509915/converting-camel-case-to-underscore-case-in-ruby

Comment: Exactly I think efficient could be interpreted in case of runtime or DRYness. I interpreted it to mean briefness but you are right about the runtime.