# Ruby on rails: replace camel case with space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert camel case words like `camelCase` to `CAMEL CASE`. I tried the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842444/ruby-on-rails-converting-somewordhere-to-some-word-here).

```
@q = params[:promo].underscore.humanize.upcase
```

But this gives me `CAMELCASE` and not `CAMEL CASE` same result on using:

```
@q = params[:promo].gsub(/[a-zA-Z](?=[A-Z])/, '\0 ').downcase
```

**EDIT:** the url contains `/camelCase` but on using params[:promo], the camel case is not retained and @q is `camelcase`

Comment: Your approach is correct and returns correct result in my console. Are you sure you your `params[:promo]` is `camelCase`, not `camelcase`?

Comment: @BroiSatse: You are right, the url has `/camelCase`. But on using `params[:promo]` it becomes `camelcase`.

Comment: It does work. Btw awesome Regex :)

Comment: Could you check url headers for given request? `request.original_url`

Comment: @BroiSatse : it shows `camelCase`

Comment: Do you have anything like `route_downcaser` installed. Also, what operating system is your server running on?

Comment: @BroiSatse: i am not aware of any downcaser. But what I did was, used the required part from `request.original_url` and apllied the solution mentioned in the question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 35):

```
»  'camelCase'.underscore.humanize.upcase
=> "CAMEL CASE"
```

Comment: Uri strings must be a format with dashes and underscores (not with any kind of cammelcase) also its SEO well format

Answer (score 7):

If anyone need something like 'CamelCase' to 'Camel Case' can use

```
'CamelCase'.underscore.split('_').collect{|c| c.capitalize}.join(' ')
```

Or 'CamelCase' to 'camel case'

```
'CamelCase'.underscore.split('_').join(' ')
```

Or 'CamelCase' to 'Camel case'

```
'CamelCase'.underscore.humanize
```

N.B: This solution is rails specific, it does not work in ruby without ActiveSupport.

Comment: `'CamelCase'.underscore.titleize` also returns "Camel Case" - a lot easier than your suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Just replace your upper characters fist with itself prepended with a space and then make everything uppercase

```
'camelCase'.gsub(/[A-Z]/, ' \0').upcase
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'camelCase'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ').upcase
```