# How can I rename the keys so that they are underscored

Tags: ruby

Here is a ruby hash:

```
a = {
  :testOne => 1,
  :testTwo => 2
}
```

How can I rename the keys so that they are underscored?

```
a = {
  :test_one => 1,
  :test_two => 2
}
```

Ken Bloom got me on the right tract here. You do need ActiveSupport or Rails3. You don't need any specific gems for this solution however:

```
hash = Hash[a.map {|k,v| [k.to_s.underscore.to_sym, v]}]
```

Thanks ken!

Comment: ActiveSupport is a gem, but using a gem is not inherently bad as long as it is one that is very popular, such as ActiveSupport. The bigger issue is that ActiveSupport is a very large gem, so you want to grab only the parts you need: `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Hash[a.map { |k,v| [k.to_s.downcase.sub('test','test_').to_sym, v] }]
```

*Update:* If you need to find the common root string, you can use this:

```
root = a.keys.inject do |m, e|
    s = m.to_s
    s.chop! while !e.to_s.start_with? s
    s
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, how is this better than the solution I a adjusted from Ken's answer?

Comment: As you can see, this doesn't use the method `underscore` or `to_h` which are parts of other gems.  What @DigitalRoss has provided here doesn't require either, but will do the conversion about which you inquired.

Comment: `sub('test','test_')` How is this dynamic or could it be made to be dynamic?

Comment: ThisIsNotTheMostGeneralWayToConvertCamelCaseStringsToUnderscores. it_will_fail_with_the_first_sentence_of_this_answer. ThatIsWhyIUsedActiveSupport. but_you_can_also_look_at_the_answers_in_the_comment_by_G_A.

Comment: @Ken, sure, but that answer was already posted, and there seemed to be some interest in a simplified solution. Sometimes you don't find out what the OP really wanted until you try something.

Answer (score 2):

This answer requires the facets gem, and activesupport (which is part of rails).

```
require 'active_support'
require 'facets'

a.map{|k,v| [k.to_s.underscore.to_sym, v]}.to_h
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^ from facets
#                  from activesupport
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am looking for a way to do this without a gem.

Comment: +1, I delete my answer, you were faster. Use Hash[...] is facets is not available. Note that also that this creates a new hash (which is the right thing to do!)

Comment: Camelcase to underscore code can be found in the answer to this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509915/converting-camel-case-to-underscore-case-in-ruby