# Best Way to underscore params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, parameters

I'm writing REST JSON services for Android and iOS mobile devices, but Ruby, Java and Objecive-C have different code styles. I'm looking for best way to write code in Ruby style, but consider the requirements of other languages. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure it's a suitable question for SO. Anyway the best resource out there is the book Eloquent Ruby, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Many rails developers have run into this issue. The JSON and JavaScript best practice is to use camelCase for property names.

I found usinging .camelize(:lower) on any returned JSON to be the easiest way to do this.

The other conversion from camelCase to under_score is described here: [Converting camel case to underscore case in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509915/converting-camel-case-to-underscore-case-in-ruby)

I have looked for something close to C#'s JSON.NET for Ruby as far as flexibility, but have not found it.