# ruby on rails, instance_variable_set 'variable' not allowed as instance variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been looking at this for some time, with no luck.

I am working with Ruby on Rails. I am attempting to use .each to iterate through an array and use each element to set a variable name. Specifically, the variable will control whether the checkbox on a form is displayed as checked.

I keep recieving this error: `@PG-13_check' is not allowed as an instance variable name
It seems like prior problems involving this error revolve around a failure to declare the instance variable with @. But I have included that.

Model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible, :title, :rating, :description, :release_date 
  def self.ratings 
    ratings = [G, PG, PG-13, R] 
  end
 end
```

Controller Code:

```
@movies = Movie.all
@all_ratings = Movie.ratings
@all_ratings.each do |x| 
  instance_variable_set("@#{x}_check", "true")
end
```

In turn, the view reads:

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, checked = @#{rating}_check, :id => "ratings_#{rating}"
```

Comment: Are you sure numbers and hyphens are allowed in Ruby variable names? If I recall corrected, hyphens aren't, and I'm not sure about numbers.

Comment: I think numbers are allowed but the hyphen isn't.

Comment: class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible, :title, :rating, :description, :release_date
 def self. ratings
  ratings = [G, PG, PG-13, R]
end

Comment: Add `Movie` model in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Just double-checked, and Ruby variables aren't allowed to have hyphens in them. Only numbers, letters, and underscores are -- i.e., if it doesn't match `/[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/` it isn't an allowed variable name. This means that you can't declare a variable named `PG-13_check`. However, you *could* declare one called `PG13_check`, which is (IMO) clear enough. You can get that with a very simple application of `String#gsub`:

```rb
x.gsub('-', '')
```

So in your code, this would look like:

```rb
@all_ratings.each do |x| 
  instance_variable_set("@#{x.gsub('-', '')}_check", "true")
end
```

If you want to convert it back to the original form, you could use something like this instead:

```rb
@all_ratings.each do |x| 
  instance_variable_set("@#{x.gsub('-', '_')}_check", "true")
end
```

Then, to get `x` back, you can get the string form and use:

```rb
variable_name.split('_')[1..-2].join('_').gsub '_', '-'
```

That probably isn't the most efficient way, but it's the first that I thought of. What it does is strip off the `_check` at the end (`.split('_')[1..-2].join('_')`), then replace all `_` with `-`.

Comment: An identifier can't start with a digit.

Comment: Thanks!  

Can I apply the same method in the view though? In other words, I am using a predetermined model, Movies with :ratings that = PG-13.  Therefore, when I iterate through :ratings to create the checkbox form, I would need to .gsub the '-' so that it matches the instance variable in my controller.

Comment: Well, you can use the full range of unicode word characters in variable names, plus some special chars like `_`. Some exceptions apply on order to have a sane parser. E.g., it can't start with a number on order to prevent the thing to be parses as a number. Apart from that, you are free to use whatever you like, even this: `ಠ_ಠ`

Comment: @iammurp Would stripping the '_check' and gsubbing underscores for hyphens work, or are there other considerations you haven't shown that prevent that? If that'd work I'll put it in now.

Comment: It would not work because I cannot change the Movie :rating "PG-13", and in the view, I have to iterate through the ratings to get the variable names, including "PG-13" -- so the _check is not the problem.  The problem was (a) including "-" in the variable name, and even if I remove the "-" with gsub, (b) removing the "-" from the variable in the view to match the instance variable created in the controller.

Comment: I was having a similar problem. I resolved using the **underscore** method which lets you do `'my-string'.underscore` and returns `my_string`. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1509939/1498118)

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner, so I hope I don't look bad for missing something that was too obvious and, hence, wasting everyone's time.  But I ultimately just put a conditional statement in my check_box tag, which accomplished my task. This is for an edx class, so I won't put the actual answer.  It was to the effect of:

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, checked = does the params hash includes the rating that was checked true ? false, :id => "ratings_#{rating}"
```

Thanks for all the responses, I learned a lot!