# How can I write this Ruby gsub using Python re?

Tags: python, ruby, regex

I got this following function in Ruby which uses `gsub`.

```
def class_to_endpoint(klass)
  klass.name.split('::').last.
    gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
    gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
    tr("-", "_").
    downcase
end
```

How can I implement this in Python re? Please help me

Tried this on irb console and and I can give few examples, basically adds an underscore bw each word in camelcase syntax

1. `UserProfile` -> `user_profile`
2. `LastModifiedTime` -> `last_modified_time`
3. `User-Profile` -> `user_profile`

Answer:
I think this is all I wanted -> [Elegant Python function to convert CamelCase to snake_case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case)

Copied from the above link and modified a bit

```
def class_to_endpoint(name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).replace('-', '_').lower()
```

Comment: Post an example along with expected output.

Comment: I have no idea what is the expected output, I am trying to convert this code to Python.

Comment: `I  have no idea what is the expected output`, then in what basis you accept an answer if posted.

Comment: Please find the examples, does that looks fine?

Comment: folks, why downvote? I have added some examples. please check

Comment: Please fix the downvote

Comment: Folks, Can anyone tell me the reason for the downwote? because of it I no longer post questions on SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A  python one-liner will do this job.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = ['LastModifiedTime','UserProfile','User-Profile']
>>> [re.sub(r'(^|([a-z])\W?)([A-Z])', lambda m: m.group(2)+'_'+ m.group(3).lower() if m.group(1) else m.group(3).lower(), i) for i in s]
['last_modified_time', 'user_profile', 'user_profile']
```

Comment: Marking this answer as a correct answer as it has the Python code. Which matches the title of the question. For every other reader's good.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to get a class and convert its *CamelCase* name to a *snake_case* one.

Let me try to explain it:

```
klass.name.split('::').last
```

Namespaces in ruby are achieved through nesting classes in modules or other classes. For example:

```
module API
  class Service2URLMapper
  end
end
```

Now `Service2URLMapper` can be referenced with `API::Service2URLMapper`. This is what is given to the method here. Splitting by `::` and getting the last element will give you the name of the class without the namespace prefix. In this case `Service2URLMapper`.

```
gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2')
```

This will split any sequence of two or more capital letters at the position of the last capital letter with a `_` if the sequence is followed by a lowercase letter. For example:

```
"Service2URLMapper".gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2') # => "Service2URL_Mapper"
```

The next part is

```
gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2')
```

which will similarly split after a digit, if it was preceded by a lower case letter and followed by a capital letter:

```
"Service2URL_Mapper".gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2') # => "Service2_URL_Mapper"
```

The two regexes should be the same in python.

After that `tr("-", "_")` will simply replace `-` with `_`. I have no idea who uses dashes in their class names, but apparently the author decided it was necessary.

And finally `downcase` just does what you would expect.

So everything in action gives us:

```
class_to_endpoint(API::Service2URLMapper) # => "service2_url_mapper"
```

Comment: The code seems to be from ActiveSupport's underscore method from strings, which is even more complex nowadays: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L91-L100, see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509915/converting-camel-case-to-underscore-case-in-ruby

Comment: @BrunoE., that is what I thought. Still, what is this `-` to `_` spiel? Can you give an example of a famous class with a dash in its name?

Comment: @ndn thanks a lot for the explanation. seems like this one does it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175208/elegant-python-function-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case

Comment: @ndn found https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6c95e9b14697a9527ab761d1a084f6bc61af56b9 which introduced it long time ago